# Executing a SQL Server stored procedure from a historian calculation

Tags: stored-procedures, historian, proficy

Using Historian 5.5 and SQL Server 2012.

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server called `perfEng_RWtopits` and I want to call this procedure from within a calculation tag in Historian Administrator.

The stored procedure returns one `float` value.

I have the following code so far:

```
   Dim sql
   Dim con 
   Dim cmd
   Dim value

   sql = "perfEng_RWtopits"
   Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   con.ConnectionString =  "myconnectionstring"
   con.Open                        
   Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   cmd.ActiveConnection = con
   cmd.CommandText = sql                   
   value = cmd.Execute

   con.close
   Set cmd = Nothing
   Set con = Nothing
```

When I test the calculation I get a value of zero and a quality of bad. If I execute the stored procedure within SQL Server I get 17.123554 (which is correct). Also if I add the following to the end.

```
Result = value
```

I get the following error message.

[image: Historian Error Message]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your vb script. To bad that we can't debug that in Historian Administrator in calcullation tab.

When using a parameterless function you can execute it by writing:
`FunctionName`
or 
`FunctionName()`, but when you want to pass the result to a variable then you must use `()` like this `value = FunctionName()`.

You are using function `cmd.Execute` without `()` and returning the result to `value`. Just fix the line 
`value = cmd.Execute`
to
`value = cmd.Execute()`